# Loose SATA to USB cable lead to disk corruption?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I am currently booting linux off of an external SSD through a SATA to USB cable. Now, this cable is quite loose - I mean, simply touching the wire causes the drive to disconnect. Is this going to lead to a corrupted disk? In fact, what exactly happens when an SSD gets disconnected during usage?

Comment: It depends.  It could happen.  If you are worried you should stop using the cable.

Comment: Yes  this is likely to lead to bad/incomplete data being written. Journalling filesystems can somewhat help here but its still a bad idea.

Comment: Not only can it lead to corruption but it can also lead to false signs of corruption if the i/o stream is interrupted, meaning you'll not only be trying to fix things that are broken but also things that are not really broken.  This way madness lies.. [Been there, done that, learned to recognise the signs]Just buy a new cable.

Comment: New cable it is then :)